# Default to page index on page load

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pageload

I have a gridview that is used to update a database.  I am having a problem with the display at startup.  The problem is that the page index should be 0 indicating that the gridview should start on the first page.

Here is what I thought should work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvSummary.PageIndex = 0;
            gvSummary.DataBind();
            this.BindData();
            dlAnnoType.SelectedValue = "Agency Error";

        }
    }
```

The page is going to whatever I had left off at in the previous session.  I am hoping I can resolve this because I am using similar logic after I update a row in the gridview.  According to the people who are checking my work, I have not accomplished this.  I need to default to the first page on start and retain the page after update.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: you're off to a rocky start if you don't know the difference between asp classic and asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check what the BindData function actually does. I think it is populating the GridView from a Sesssion and setting the PageIndex. Try setting the PageIndex after binding the GridView like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
        gvSummary.PageIndex = 0;
        gvSummary.DataBind();
        dlAnnoType.SelectedValue = "Agency Error";

    }
}
```

P.S: `this` is not needed here

Comment: I thought about it after the  post and tried it late last night.  You are correct sir.